# Setting different RTP SSRCs with GStreamer and multiudpsink

Tags: c++, gstreamer, rtp, gstreamer-1.0

In a `C++` program I'm using a `GStreamer` pipeline to generate an `RTP` stream and send it to two destinations at the same time with a `multiudpsink` element.

This works fine, except that both streams have the same `RTP SSRC`. Is there a way to set different `SSRC`s for the two streams ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was to use a `tee` element and have multiple legs that each have their own RTP encoder (in my case `rtpopuspay`) and `multiupdsink` element.

That way each feeds gets a different SSRC.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no way.**

**The `SSRC` is a unique identifier of the participant to a `RTP` session.**
The **`RTP` session manager** hold the `SSRC`s of all participants. The Unique Identifier `SSRC` cannot be duplicated and different `SSRC`s correspond to different participants to the session.
**So `SSRC` is not the identifier of the session or of a pair of participants, is the identifier of a single user.**

In your case, the `SSRC` is the identifier of the generator of the `RTP` stream so is impossible to have 2 different `SSRC` in this case.

Further read [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtpsession.html)